# Can I restore duplicity back up files following clean install of an upgrade distro?

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu  14.04 lts to 16.04.  installation was interrupted and now the only desktop environment is LXDE.  Unity nor Gnome will log in.  I have tried the to get updates, and they are unable to fetch as the network LAN connection doesn't appear to be functioning properly.  I have been suggested to get driver packages.  No network connection.

I did create a USB image of 16.04 which works perfectly when booted.  The option to repair is not available.  I have two options both indicate it will erase all my files, or creating a third system to boot into(Currently dual boot already).

I have a back up using the Duplicity software for my files using 14.04.
If I choose a clean install from the USB image, my question is regarding access of my files that are stored on an external hard drive.

Will I be able to restore the files to the new system, or at least access them?

Comment: I think it depends on what was backed up, documents yes but system files and programs I doubt that

Comment: I have a back up of /home